# I am getting a 'Sum' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am summing a variable. I also want the format of this variable to have the thousand separator in it. I am using the following code and getting the error in the title. any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
Convert (varchar(10),CAST(Sum(ar.chgamt as Int),1))
,Sum(ar.curbal) as CurBal
FROM rpt_dat_ARDetail ar
WHERE reportmonth = '06/01/2013' AND uci = 'VIT'
GROUP BY ar.curbal,ar.chgamt
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the nesting. You're saying `CAST(SUM(ar.chgamt AS INT),1)` which is not valid.

That specific source of syntax error can be corrected by:

```
Convert (varchar(10),SUM(CAST(ar.chgamt as Int)))
```

However the query will still not likely work as expected as written even after fixing that.

I am not sure why you are converting to int and then to varchar or why you have a `GROUP BY` at all when you are `SUM`ming both columns. If you show sample data (including data type definitions and an explanation of why you are storing something `SUM`mable in a string column) and desired results, we can help you with the query.

Comment: Using SELECT ,Convert (varchar(10),SUM(CAST(ar.chgamt as INT)) ,Sum(ar.curbal) as CurBal FROM rpt_dat_ARDetail ar     I get an Incorrect syntax near ','. error

Comment: I removed the extra comma. SELECT 
Convert (varchar(10),SUM(CAST(ar.chgamt as INT))
,Sum(ar.curbal) as CurBal
FROM rpt_dat_ARDetail ar
I now get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: The conversion is to add the thousand separator

Comment: Impossible to debug your current statement in a comment. Anyway as for thousand separators, do that at the client.